# Pass a parameter to existing onClick JS function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Very basic question, but how can I add/populate a parameter to the onClick function of an HTML element?

```
<a onClick="someFunction()" id="testLink">Some function</a>

//PSEUDO CODE
var someFunctionParam = document.getElementById('testLink');
someFunctionParam.addParameter(someParam);
```

Obviously "addParameter" isn't a valid method in Javascript, can anyone guide on how to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way in my opinion is to rewrite you JS to something like this:

```
<a onclick="aNewFunction()" id="testLink">Some function</a>


function aNewFunction() {
  // Invoke your existing function here;
  someFunction();

  //PSEUDO CODE
  var someFunctionParam = document.getElementById('testLink');
  someFunctionParam.addParameter(someParam);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Best way I would think of is

```
$(function () {
    var parameter='Joe Root';
    var functionName = $('#testLink').attr("onclick");
    $('#testLink').attr("onclick",
    functionName.replace('()', "('" + parameter + "')"));
    alert($('#testLink').attr("onclick"));
});

function someFunction(name) {
    alert("Hi " + name);
}
```

As, you can see, this works http://jsfiddle.net/hXpSN/1/